# PHP Slash is not throwing 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

The Problem exists on simple PHP-Webpage without CMS.

There exists an index.php
File: https://www.example.com/index.php

The Problem now is, if i make a call like https://www.example.com/index.php/abcnotexisting
 the Server don't thrown a **404 Error**, the index.php will parsed normally.

How can i reach, that only /index.php can be called and not index.php/xyz?

Thanks for a short hint.

br Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **htaccess** file.

Like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,R=301]
```

Dont forget to activ **mod_rewrite**, **RewriteEngine On** and the **RewriteBase**. (base directory).